# Debug mode breaks when setting addAspxExtension to true

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

When we set the **addAspxExtension** web.config setting to true for our website, debug mode stops working for all pages of our site except for the homepage. When I say that it stops working I mean that it displays the actual page but without the Sitecore ribbon and profiling information.

I guess we could apply this setting only in our content delivery environments and leave it on (addAspxExtension="true") for our content entry environment but I was wondering if anyone has managed to get around this issue?

### Update

Until Sitecore resolves this issue I have decided to only set the **addAspxExtension** setting to "true" in our Preview and Production environments. That way the debug mode will still work in our development environment.

Comment: Which Sitecore version are you using?

Comment: @ruud-van-falier I'm using the latest 6.5 release (111230)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now, this issue is a bug that Sitecore is aware of and should hopefully be fixed by the next update.  There are basically 2 workarounds for it:

1. Set the addAspxExtension attribute to “false” value.
2. Manually write the .aspx extension to other URLs which are different from the home page.

Hope that helps..

Comment: Marked it as the answer although I wouldn't say that setting the addAspxExtension attribute to 'False' is a workaround if you are trying to achieve extensionless URL's AND have the Debug mode working